# Kotlin constructor reference in Intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

It is not really a Kotlin question, maybe an Intellij question, I don't know.

Assume we have a data class

```
data class Person(val name: String = "untitled", val age: Int = 20)
```

And we have a function

```
fun factory(cstr: ()->Person) : Person {
    return cstr()
}
```

Then we can invoke `factory(::Person)` and obtain an instance of Person class with default constructor parameters.

The `fun factory` can be invoked successfully wherever. But in IntelliJ I get a red underline error

[image]

Look like the IDE failed to recognize that there is a default constructor.

However, If I change the code like that, the error goes away. Everything runs perfectly and no error is shown in the IDE.

[image]

I am using IntelliJ 2020.2 and Kotlin 1.4.10.

Maybe it is about some IntelliJ inspection rules, but I cannot find one related.

Further, it is a piece of old code that showed no error before (maybe 5 months ago). I am not sure what has bee change since then caused the error.

So the problem is why is Intellij show error for lambda version and not for KFunction version?

Comment: I think that would be a compiler or IDE bug. Type inference has been rewritten in Kotlin 1.4 and might not work well in all cases. I suggest to file a bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: @deamon follow up at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42055

Answer (score 0):

I assume invoking `factory` like this works fine:

```
factory(() -> Person())
```

Then it seems your version of the Kotlin IDE plugin does not handle constructor references well in this case.  The compiler does, since the code works.  If the IDE plugin version is the latest, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the problem with old inference enabled in the `build.gradle` file: `freeCompilerArgs += ["-XXLanguage:-NewInference"]`. Please make sure you're using new (default) type inference in Kotlin 1.4+. So, remove the compiler argument, that should fix the IDE highlighting after Gradle project reimport into IDEA.